# clusterR not processing on disk when it should

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a set of large rasters stored as .rds files, like

```
saveRDS(getwd(), readAll(raster))
```

(they're half the size of GTiffs and I don't need to open them in a GIS). Turning them into a stack via

```
rdses  <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = '\\.rds$', full.names = TRUE)
maplist <- lapply(map_rds, function(x) readRDS(x))
mapstack <- raster::stack(map_list)
```

is fine, but when I send the rds-based stack to clusterR for further processing, e.g.

```
beginCluster(2)
clusterR(mapstack, calc, args (fun = myfun(x)), export = 'value')
endCluster()
```

R keeps trying to run the whole operation in memory, even though canProcessInMemory(mapstack) returns FALSE. The operation always crashes due to lack of spare RAM.

This doesn't happen if I save the rasters as GeoTiffs, then stack those and send to clusterR - temp gri/grd files are created as they should be and RAM usage is low.

Is there a way to make sure the rds-based stack is handled the same way as the GeoTiff based stack?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this does not work with rds files, but maybe you can try to force library raster to work on disk:

```
if(raster:::.toDisk() != TRUE) {
  setOptions(todisk = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I gave it a shot, but it has no effect in this case. If you look at the raster source code, the option is only used to force `canProcessInMemory()` to return `FALSE`, and it was already doing that (and, I guess, being ignored somehow). Given that reading all my rds files in does have the potential to fill the RAM of a smaller machine anyway, I think I'll just have to stick with using GTIFF for raster files.